# Regex with remove before and first after

Tags: regex

I have a simple example as follows

`user=djdjdjjdjdjdj; user=jdjdjdjdjdj;`

And

`user=djdjdjjdjdjdj;user=jdjdjdjdjdj;`

Differences in white space between the two examples above. When I used Regex to separate user codes, it ok with first example. Can you advise me how to do better, this is my Regex code:

`(?<=user=)([^\s]+)(?=;)`

Comment: What is your matching criteria? What do you need as your result?

Comment: Look at first example that is correct.  But the data entered must have spaces, I want if no spaces remain the same.

Comment: It's still not clear.  Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/TC0GMU/1  Is it what you were asking about?

Comment: Seblor below correct my idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match `[^\s]` but also a space, simply use `.`.

So your regex would be [`(?<=user=)(.+?)(?=;)`](https://regex101.com/r/eSzyX0/1) (with a non greedy quantifier to match until the next character is a `;`).
Or you can match until the first `;`, use this : [`(?<=user=)([^;]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/pkXtgo/1)

Answer (score 2):

I would just use here:

```
(?<=user=)[^;]+
```

### Demo

This would match each `user` value, sans semi colon, which appears in the input.  If you really want to use capture groups, then I suggest not even using the lookbehind:

```
\buser=([^;]+)
```

This would place each user value in the first capture group.